# Map not visible after Animation

Tags: android, animation, dictionary, android-framelayout

i swipe my activity with below code:

```
    Animation anim;
    int w = activityView.getMeasuredWidth();
    int h = activityView.getMeasuredHeight();
    int left = (int) (activityView.getMeasuredWidth() * 0.8);
    if (!menuOut) {
        anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, left, 0, 0);
        menuView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        animParams.init(left, 0, left + w, h);
    } else {            
        anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, -left, 0, 0);
        animParams.init(0, 0, w, h);
    }
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setAnimationListener(this);        
    anim.setFillAfter(true);        
    activityView.startAnimation(anim);

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    System.out.println("onAnimationEnd");

    menuOut = !menuOut;
    if (!menuOut) {
        menuView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    activityView.layout(animParams.left, animParams.top, animParams.right,  animParams.bottom);     
    activityView.clearAnimation();
}
```

Here `menuView` and `activityView`  are two layout in `framelayout`.

In `activityview` i have one google map problem is that when i return from `menuview` to `activityview` map is hide.and both view in same activity so onresume also not call when i return to `activityview`.

so anybody can help to keep map after animation?

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in onAnimationEnd(Animation animation). Why not set the visibility of MapView to View.VISIBLE, and when is the above peice of code invoked. Throw in more code, explainations for better understanding.